# How to transfer variable to routes.index

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, data-transfer

In file `app.js` i have:

```
  , mongoose = require('mongoose')
  , db = mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/expressdb');

  app.get('/', routes.index);
```

and i have file `routes/index.js`, If I want to transfer `db` variable to `routes.index` What should I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've setup an example on how you can achieve that, by passing the db as a parameter to the route module, and that module returns a function (in which db is visible):

**routes.index**

```
module.exports = function (db) {
  return function(req, res, next) {
    // you can access db here
  }
}
```

**app.js**

```
...
routes = {};
routes.index = require('./routes')(db);
...
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it's fairly standard in libraries that connect to a database for the connection to be shared if you try to create another connection (ie: the DB interface is a singleton). You could try simply calling

```
db = mongoose.connect('mongodb://localeyes/expressdb');
```

in your routes/index.js file, and it will likely use the same connection. I'd recommend reading the code to see if it will use an existing connection or if it tries to reconnect every time you call it.

edit: on second thought, you have another, less savory option:
You could make it global like so

```
global.db = db;
```

and then in your routes/index.js

var db = global.db;